# Is there a C library for machine learning?

Tags: library, c, machine-learning

When searching for a C library for machine learning, I encounter many results of 'C/C++' libraries. However, C and C++ are obviously different languages, and these libraries seem to be exclusively written in C++. A quick google search of "C machine learning library" will yield examples of this.

I was wondering if there were any machine learning libraries strictly for C? I am often told that although C is difficult, it is backed by a vast number of libraries. As such, I find it confusing as to why I haven't been able to find any machine learning libraries?

Any suggestions of good machine learning libraries for C?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about what functionality the library should provide?

Comment: @mawg I'm just curious as to which libraries are available, as well as which libraries are considered the 'best'. I realise this is vague and broad, and I apologise for that. I am a newbie who is looking to use my C programming skills to learn and implement machine learning. I don't have any specific algorithms in mind; I would like something that will allow me to develop my machine learning skills. Hopefully this provides so further clarification.

Comment: Does it have to be coded in C? Will you be reading the code, or changing it? If you just want to use it, then almost every language has C bindings ...

Comment: @Mawg I only know how to program in C. I have also never used bindings. Will these enable me to use C++ machine learning libraries in C, without actually understanding C++? If so, then I am fine with doing this.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation. I think that you will find that the API for those C++ libraries is pure C.

Comment: @Mawg I will do so. Thank you for your assistance.